# Splitting of Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

Suppse E is a cohomology theory which has Kunneth Formula, i.e $ E(A \wedge B)= E(A) \otimes_{E(pt)} E(B) $.  What happens to the Atiyah Hirzebruch Spectral sequence while we compute $ E(A \wedge B) $?   The 
$ E^2 $ page of the spectral sequence has the relatively simple form in terms of the singular cohomology theory of $H^{*}(A \wedge B, \pi_{*}(E))$ which in turn can be expressed in terms of $H^{*}A, H^{*}B$.
   Does the spectral sequence splits? $ \\  \\ $
It is been discussed in [Tensor product of spectral sequences?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27722/tensor-product-of-spectral-sequences) that, there is no natural construction for the tensor product of spectral sequence.
In my special situation can we define it for Atiyah Hirzebruch Spectral sequence? 
I am interested in the case when A,B are finite CW spectra.  Kindly refer me the source where I can get some idea.

Comment: Actually the thread you quote says that there is natural construction for the tensor product in the case you are talking about.

Comment: It may not be a spectral sequence because of Kunneth formula.

Comment: The point is that since A and B are supposed to be finite, the Kunneth isomorphism holds only in very few cases (there won't be situations like Landweber-flat), so you get Kunneth isomorphism everywhere in sight. That is either $\pi _*(E)$ is field, or one of $H_^*(A)$ or $H^*(B)$ is torsion-free.  Thus $H^*(A\times B \pi_*(E))\cong H^*(A),\pi _*(E))\times H^*(B),\pi _*(E))$